# cant compile install and Configure any linux kernel in debian 7

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, compiling

I followed these steps from the link: (http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-compile-and-install-linux-kernel-3-0-in-ubuntu-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/) but these commands don't work:

```
sudo make modules_install install
sudo make
sudo make oldconfig
sudo make menuconfig
```

#### Error message

[image: ss of error]

Comment: What error messages did you get?

Comment: the error massage http://postimg.org/image/wpbsuxowl/

Comment: Rather than both images and links you should copy and paste the text in your terminal into the post for future search possibilities.

Comment: By the way, you don't need `sudo` if you are logged in as root. I also respectfully submit that if you don't know what's wrong and how to fix it when you get `make: command not found` you really have no business compiling your own kernel.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing at least some of the development tools required to build the kernel.  If you do

```
apt-get install make gcc
```

that will get you going.  There might be more packages required, but you certainly won't be able to build the kernel without those two.

Comment: Installing the `build-essential` package is also be a good idea and for running *menuconfig* you need `libncurses5-dev`, too.

Comment: Ach I knew I forgot something obvious -- thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the build tools to compile applications. You'll need to install the packages that provide the tools `make`, `gcc`, etc.

```
$ sudo apt-get install make gcc
```

Comment: `make` doesn't depend on `gcc` so this will not be enough.

Comment: I know but he's most likely going to need more than `make` and `gcc` so spoon feeding him those 2 packages doesn't solve his real problem anyway. He's likely just going to get tripped up by missing libraries etc.

Comment: @scai - I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do any compilation, install the [build-essential](http://packages.debian.org/build-essential) package. This pulls in GCC, make and other basic development tools.

I recommend using kernels packaged for Debian. If you compile your own, you'll have to get the configuration right, and to install it properly. Getting the configuration right is difficult, as there are many options; you'll probably forget an essential component the first time, and it can be difficult to figure out what's missing. Furthermore Debian sets up its system with an [initramfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs#Initramfs_in_comparison_with_initrd); if you go with an initramfs, you'll have to regenerate it with the modules you've compiled, which Debian's setup scripts do automatically. If you don't use an initramfs, you'll have to make sure that all the necessary drivers are in the main kernel image and not in a module. You'll also need to make sure to register your new kernel with your bootloader correctly.

Debian provides the [kernel-package](http://packages.debian.org/kernel-package) program to build a kernel the Debian way. Use it. In addition to pulling in all the dependencies you were missing, it'll take care of packaging the kernel properly.